# Pivot spark dataframe array of kv pairs into individual columns

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pivot

I have following schema:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- config: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- entry: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

There will not be more than 3 key-value pairs (k1,k2,k3) in the array and I would like to make value from each key into its own column while the corresponding data would come from the value from the same kv pair.

```
+--------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
|id      |date      |k1        |k2        |k3       |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
|    id1 |2019-08-12|id1-v1    |id1-v2    |id1-v3   |
|    id2 |2019-08-12|id2-v1    |id2-v2    |id2-v3   |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
```

So far I tried something like this:

```
sourceDF.filter($"someColumn".contains("SOME_STRING"))
      .select($"id", $"date", $"config.entry" as "kvpairs")
      .withColumn($"kvpairs".getItem(0).getField("key").toString(), $"kvpairs".getItem(0).getField("value"))
      .withColumn($"kvpairs".getItem(1).getField("key").toString(), $"kvpairs".getItem(1).getField("value"))
      .withColumn($"kvpairs".getItem(2).getField("key").toString(), $"kvpairs".getItem(2).getField("value"))
```

But in this case, the column names are shown as `kvpairs[0][key]`, `kvpairs[1][key]` and `kvpairs[2][key]` as shown below:

```
+--------+----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|id      |date      |kvpairs[0][key]|kvpairs[1][key]|kvpairs[2][key]|
+--------+----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|    id1 |2019-08-12|    id1-v1     |    id1-v2     |   id1-v3      |
|    id2 |2019-08-12|    id2-v1     |    id2-v2     |   id2-v3      |
+--------+----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Two questions:

- Is my approach right? Is there a better and easier way to pivot this
  such that I get one row per array with the 3 kv pairs as 3 columns? I want to handle cases where order of the kv pairs may differ.
- If the above approach is fine, how do I alias the column name to the data of the "key" element in the array?

Comment: Your approach is probably optimal. Use `alias` to rename the columns. Also- you tagged pyspark but your code looks like `scala`.

Comment: how to use alias inside withColumn programmatically such that the column name is the data corresponding to the key. For example: [[a,1],[b,2],[c,3]] .I want column name to be a,b,c and values to be 1,2,3 respectively. An example snippet might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using multiple `withColumn` together with `getItem` will not work since the order of the kv pairs may differ. What you can do instead is explode the array and then use `pivot` as follows:

```
sourceDF.filter($"someColumn".contains("SOME_STRING"))
  .select($"id", $"date", explode($"config.entry") as "exploded")
  .select($"id", $"date", $"exploded.*")
  .groupBy("id", "date")
  .pivot("key")
  .agg(first("value"))
```

The usage of `first` inside the aggregation here assumes there will be a single value for each key. Otherwise `collect_list` or `collect_set` can be used.

Result:

```
+---+----------+------+------+------+
|id |date      |k1    |k2    |k2    |
+---+----------+------+------+------+
|id1|2019-08-12|id1-v1|id1-v2|id1-v3|
|id2|2019-08-12|id2-v1|id2-v2|id2-v3|
+---+----------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm! If the ordering stayed fixed, im assuming the withColumn approach would work  correct?

Comment: @arjunj: Yes, that is correct. If that is the case then first finding the key names from the first row in the dataframe and then apply these using `alias`/`as` in the `withColumn` would work. In this way the headers would be correct.